# "java: cannot find symbol" error in Spring Security

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spring-security, pom.xml

I have been trying to run the application but it throws an error called like that

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class UserDetailsServiceImpl
  location: package com.project.questapp.services
```

I am taking 8 errors. 3 of them are these. I have checked the locations of the classes which causes error but I could not find any mistake. My pom.xml maybe incorrect, but I rerun it lonely, it run clearly. What is the reason behind the error?

```
package com.project.questapp.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;

import com.project.questapp.security.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint; // it causes to the error
import com.project.questapp.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter; // it causes to the error
import com.project.questapp.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl; // it causes to the error

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig{
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint handler;

    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService, JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint handler) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        config.addAllowedMethod("HEAD");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(handler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/posts")
                .permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/comments")
                .permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}
```

my pom.xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>questapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>questapp</name>
    <description>QuestApp project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can run `mvn package` in Terminal without any compilation errors then check your IntelliJ configuration.

- Make sure you configured the right version of Java (17 is your case) [image: Project Structure]
- Make sure you configured the right version of Maven (compare with `mvn --version` in Terminal where you built your project without any compilation errors) [image: Maven config]
- Reimport your Maven project (right click on the root module)[image: Reload Maven project]
- If 3 steps above are not helping, try Invalidate Caches and Restart [image: Invalidate Caches and Restart]

IF YOU TRIED EVERYTHING AND THE ISSUE IS STILL NOT FIXED, RESTART YOUR COMPUTER!!!

Comment: My java version is correct, I have done invalidate caches and restart and reload project. Nothing changed. However, I want to say that firstly, I have opened the project on Eclipse IDE. After that, I opened it Intellij IDE and I am seeing these which are .classpath and .project with Eclipse logo. Can it cause the problem? If I code the project using direct Intellij IDE, can the problem be solved?

Comment: you can try these:
- run `mvn clean`
- delete all the files which is not related to your project  especially the hidden files (if you using Git, just re-clone it for the refresh repo)
- reimport the project using IntelliJ
- verify Java version, Maven version,... are correct
*actually the eclipse files are not really the problem

Comment: Hello, finally I could solve my problem. I rebuilded the project and everything is good. Can you offer to me some books, youtube channels to make my Spring knowledge better? I have good Java knowledge but my Spring knowledge is not as good as Java.